# SQL Insert from another table

Tags: sql, mysql

I can use some help with a sql INSERT.

```
words_table contains
  productid
  word

product table contains
  productid
  description
```

I'd like to create a row in words_table that contains the productid and the word "foundit"
for each row in product table WHERE description LIKE '%keyword%'.

and I'm not sure how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO words_table (productId, word)
   SELECT productId, 'foundit' 
   FROM product 
   WHERE description like '%keyword%'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO Words_table
SELECT ProductId, 'FoundIt'
  FROM Product
 WHERE Description LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT  words_table (productid, word)
SELECT  productid, 'foundit'
FROM    product
WHERE   description LIKE '%' + @keyword + '%'
```